# Getting System.FormatException while trying to cast

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a function to duplicate a row in DataGridView which looks like this:

```
private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;

    // If button clicked
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        // Get values what you want to use
        var value1 = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;
        var value2 = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;

        // Insert a new row behind the click one
        dgv.Rows.Insert(e.RowIndex + 1);

        // Set the previously stored values
        dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].Cells[1].Value = value1;
        dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex + 1].Cells[2].Value = value2;
    }
}
```

Now i wanted to write a function for one specific cell to increase + 1 with every click. For example: if in Cell[2] the value is 1, with the next added row the value should count up to 2, 3 and so on. I´ve tried to operate with + but i´ve got a error message that the operator cannot be applied to type of object. So i´ve tried to cast the specific cell like this:

```
 var value2 = Convert.ToInt32(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);
```

But now i get a SystemFormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you **sure** the value stored in `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value` is a numeric string? (By sure, I mean check it, not guess it). [`TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) helps

Comment: @Cid: I´ve checked with GetType() the value of that cell. It says Sytsem.String

Comment: Use try parse it tells if you conversion was possible or not, then use the boolean value to check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2 here is example

Comment: @Adir I didn't meant the type, but the content

Comment: @Cid the content is like i´ve mentioned in my example : in that case 1
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you checked if you really get 1?

Comment: @Cid I think here is an misunderstanding. I have a DataGridView and i am populating it over the view on UI. So i am the user and im am typing in some values in the cells of DGV. Now sometimes the Values are repaeting but only one column for numbers have to increase. If there are my columns with values Building: X , Room Y: Workplace: 1. So now i have for example 5 people working in the same room of the same building. I want that with every click the Value of Building and Room is duplicated and the Value of Workplace where i begin with 1 should count up with each click on the duplicate button.

Comment: My question wasn't it. My question was more *are you sure you are getting the correct cell?* `MessageBox.Show(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value);`

Answer (score 0):

Allow only numeric values as below

```
private void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    // Textbox columns
    if (dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
        if (tb != null)
        {
            tb.KeyPress += TextBox_KeyPress;
        }
    }
}

private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Only numeric characters allowed
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```